# Multipy function handles matlab

Tags: matlab, function-handle

I need to multipy two function handles and get function handle as a result.
e.g. :

```
u = @(x) x + 2;
v = @(x) 2*x + 1;
y = u * g;
```

How to do this?

Comment: I got a solution! I should `y = @(x) u(x) * g(x)`

Comment: Watch out if `x` can be a matrix or a vector!

Comment: Sure. In case of  `x` isn't matrix or a vector I should use `.*` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is

```
y = @(x)( u(x).*v(x) );
```

I dont know any other way.

Comment: that will do. May be you should just precise that the function handles `u` and `v` must be defined **before** this one (otherwise there will be no error at the time you define the function, but an error will pop up when you try to execute it).